# How do I setup pointer-keys/mouse-keys in Lubuntu? (move cursor with num-pad keys)

Tags: mouse, lubuntu, accessibility, numpad

I know there is an easy way to set up mouse emulation with the numpad in Xubuntu and Ubuntu. Is there an easy way to do so in lubuntu? is there a config file that can be edited, or does a program need to be installed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### - Enable via conf file

Create a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-enable-pointerkeys.conf`, with contents:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier             "Keyboard Defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard        "yes"
    Option                 "XkbOptions" "keypad:pointerkeys"
EndSection
```

#### - Enable for duration of session

`setxkbmap -option keypad:pointerkeys`

---

- In either case, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Num-Lock</kbd> will toggle mouse keys on/off.

Comment: Works in Raspbian.

Comment: If the pointer moves too slow, see [Setting pointerkeys (numpad as mouse keys) parameters - acceleration, delay, etc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/609367).

Comment: It works, but my mouse is set to left-handed, and I could not right-click. Turns out that you can press the `/` key once to change the `5` key to right-click.  Look up `/usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/mousekeys` for more functions.