# How can we fully control the cursor using keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, 18.04, cursor

In Lubuntu 18.04, is it possible to fully control the cursor using keyboard, equivalently to using mouse or touchpad?

For example,

- How can I left and right click?
- How can I move the cursor?
- ...

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the function you are looking for is Mouse Keys. Try the answer located here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/149651/how-do-i-setup-pointer-keys-mouse-keys-in-lubuntu-move-cursor-with-num-pad-key

Comment: Thanks. How can I right click and left click with keyboard?

Comment: [Ubuntu documentation Community Help wiki | Click and move mouse pointer using the keypad](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-mousekeys.html) My right-click (Menu) key is located next to the right Ctrl key.