# How can we make setxkbmap and xmodmap work together?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, xmodmap, xkb

On Lubuntu 18.04, I found the following commands will cancel each other

```
$ setxkbmap -option keypad:pointerkeys

$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

I would like to be able to [fully control my cursor using keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037562/how-can-we-fully-control-the-cursor-using-keyboard), with the first command.

I would like to [remap left alt key to the super key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026246/why-doesnt-my-substitution-of-the-super-key-for-the-alt-l-key-not-work-in-all-t), with the second command.

I wonder why they cancel each other? Can I get them both work? Thanks.

Comment: `xmodmap` is ancient and deprecated; it will not function at all on modern Wayland desktops.  best to stop using it entirely.

Comment: what do you use instead on Wayland desktops?  Is LXDE based on Wayland or Xwindows?

Comment: XKB is the system Wayland uses.  but system XKB only, last i checked `setxkbmap` and `xkbcomp` only funciton in X.  see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355428/222377 ... i haven't looked at LXDE in years, no idea what if they've moved to Wayland.